# Compatibility issue with Xcode generated swiftinterface file

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks

I'm working with a Cocoa Touch framework, built for distribution, which uses Core Data managed object subclasses. When I implement the framework in a client project built with the same Xcode/Swift version as the framework, the app compiles successfully.

However, when I build the framework with Xcode 11.1 (Swift 5.1), and implement the framework in a client project using Xcode 11.2.1 (Swift 5.1.2), I get a compile error in the property declaration of the generated "swiftinterface" file. "@NSManaged not allowed on computed properties"

From Framework project NSManagedObject subclass:

```
extension TestEntity {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<TestEntity> {
        return NSFetchRequest<TestEntity>(entityName: "TestEntity")
    }

    @NSManaged public var id: Int64
}
```

From Framework .swiftinterface file:

```
 @objc @NSManaged dynamic public var id: Swift.Int64 {
    @objc get
    @objc set(value)
  }
```

If I remove the setter-getter, the client app builds and runs, but I see this warning:

```
Cannot load Swift type information; AST validation error in "my_test_framework": The module file format is too old to be used by this version of the debugger.
```

Thoughts, rants, lessons, and/or workarounds are welcome!

Comment: did you find a solution for this? facing a similar problem